# How to Fix hover not working after JS script executed in HTML,CSS,JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, navigation

I was trying to make a navigation bar.

When the page loads the navigation bar works fine when mouse hover over other than navigation tabs the hover effect works the animation box follows the mouse and when the mouse is not on the navigation bar the box returns to the top link as expected.

then i click different navigation tab the animation box comes behind the clicked link but after that when i hover the mouse on other navigation bar links the animation box did not follow the mouse it stays at the active link.

Please run the code snippet to get better view of the problem.
when page loads first hover over the links than click other links.

The navigation bar only works fine on the first time as page loads.

Help would be really appreciated to fix this.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
body {
    /*background: #2c3e5e;*/
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
.navbar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 40px;
}
nav  {
    background-color: #34495e;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px ;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

nav:hover {
    width: 130px;
}

nav a{
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    position : relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
}
nav .animation {
    top: 0;
    position:absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #1abc9c;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
nav #a1:hover~.animation{
    top:0;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}
nav #a2:hover~.animation{
    top:50px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
nav #a3:hover~.animation{
    top:100px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
}

/* END of Navigation Bar */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar"> 
    <a href="#" id='a1' class="l">BioData</a>
    <a href="#" id='a2' class="l">Acadmics</a>
    <a href="#" id='a3' class="l">Complaints</a>
    <div id='animation' class="animation"></div>
  </nav>
  <script>
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('l')
    var animation = document.getElementById("animation")
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        animation.style.top = (i * 50) + "px"
        if (i == 0) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "8px 8px 0px 0px";}
        if (i == 1) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "0px 0px 0px 0px";}
        if (i == 2) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "0px 0px 8px 8px";}
      })
    }
  </script>
  <!-- Main Content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
body {
  /*background: #2c3e5e;*/
  background: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #34495e;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

nav:hover {
  width: 130px;
}

nav a {
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav .animation {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #1abc9c;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
  transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

nav #a1:hover~.animation {
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}

nav #a2:hover~.animation {
  top: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

nav #a3:hover~.animation {
  top: 100px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
}


/* END of Navigation Bar */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" id='a1' class="l">BioData</a>
    <a href="#" id='a2' class="l">Acadmics</a>
    <a href="#" id='a3' class="l">Complaints</a>
    <div id='animation' class="animation"></div>
  </nav>
  <script>
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('l')
    var animation = document.getElementById("animation")
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        animation.style.top = (i * 50) + "px"
        if (i == 0) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "8px 8px 0px 0px";
        }
        if (i == 1) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
        }
        if (i == 2) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "0px 0px 8px 8px";
        }
      })
      links[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        animation.style.top = (i * 50) + "px"
        if (i == 0) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "8px 8px 0px 0px";
        }
        if (i == 1) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
        }
        if (i == 2) {
          animation.style.borderRadius = "0px 0px 8px 8px";
        }
      })
    }
  </script>
  <!-- Main Content -->
</body>

</html>
```

hope this helps, i just added a on mouseover event

Comment: Thank you but it was not working correctly but after i added the mouse out event it solved the problem.